# First time Git user and using Ubuntu. I am running afowl of my stated goals immediately and require some assistance

Tags: github

So far I have the following information on my screen ...

```
nicholas@ubuntu:~$ git add /home/nicholas/Documents
nicholas@ubuntu:~$ git status 
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .ICEauthority
#   .Xauthority
#   .audacity-data/
#   .bash_history
#   .bash_logout
#   .bashrc
#   .cache/
#   .compiz/
#   .config/
#   .dbus/
#   .dmrc
#   .dropbox/
#   .gconf/
#   .gitconfig
#   .goutputstream-ADHZQW
#   .goutputstream-GWSJRW
#   .gstreamer-0.10/
#   .gtk-bookmarks
#   .kde/
#   .local/
#   .mission-control/
#   .mozilla/
#   .pki/
#   .profile
#   .pulse-cookie
#   .pulse/
#   .signon/
#   .thunderbird/
#   .xsession-errors
#   .xsession-errors.old
#   Desktop/
#   Downloads/
#   Dropbox/
#   Pictures/
#   Ubuntu One/
#   examples.desktop
#   git status
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
I thought that I only added the files from my Documents Directory which includes not only a .odt file from libre office but also an "officialwebsite" directory that houses a number of files that I would like to push to github. From the jump as I understand it I have added nothing and my status appears to show me that I am doing nothing even thought I am following two references ... one such reference is ... http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git ... and the other such reference is ... http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git ... I finished the code school git tutorial in about fifteen minutes with no problem and followed along nicely but in the real world things are not going so well ... can someone coach me on Git for a little bit and help me add my website and a compendium of writing from libre office to my github repository so that i can begin my journey as a git hub afficianado ... any and all help would be appreciated ... i look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it seems you have done a "git init" in your home directory.

"If you’re starting to track an existing project in Git, you need to go to the project’s directory"

```
cd /path/to/directory/with/existing/source/code
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git status
```

You may this link useful.
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository#Initializing-a-Repository-in-an-Existing-Directory

Comment: I will do this right away and get back to you. Thank you so much.

Comment: oh that worked just fine .. why do you think this crucial piece of information was not mentioned in either reference that I listed above?

Comment: @nickyisdeep: its there. I have shared a link from one of your references.

Comment: hmmmm ... i guess i overlooked something then.

Comment: I just read the tech reference that you sent. I was literally on that page and to my knowledge what you stated in terms of using the command prompt CD to change into the directory that I would like to be committed is essentially ommitted from the reference manual. I am tired and it is late but I do not see the reference point that you made in your assistance in the Git Manual whose link you provided. I could be faulty at reading right now but I would hold a point of contention to your comment that "Its there." If it is there. I missed it and only found it with your help. Thank you.